# Excel - mark if value occurs a certain number of times within a rolling time period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of attendance ids with related person ids and relevant dates. I want to mark a person id if they have attended at least 3 times within any 84 day period.

```
|Attendance ID|Person ID|Date      |
|-------------|---------|----------|
|1            |1        |01/04/18  |
|2            |1        |12/04/18  |
|3            |1        |16/05/18  |
|4            |2        |02/09/17  |
|5            |2        |16/03/18  |
|6            |2        |25/03/18  |
```

So I would like to mark person id 1 as regular but not person id 2.
I have no idea where to start!

Comment: Adding to the complexity of your question is that your date range is not continuous. Hopefully you can see that if you had a continuous date range, you could just take some kind of conditional sum in 84 day rolling windows.

Comment: I have sorted the file so that the dates are in order for each person id.

Comment: Tim, are you saying that it would be easier if the list was sorted by date rather than person id? because I can do that..

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 dates by person, you can try this :
After column Date, add this formula (column "D" I suppose):

```
=IF(DATEDIF(C2;TODAY();"D") <=84;"True";"False")
```

And finally, add this to column "E" :

```
=IF(countifs(A:A;A2;B:B;B2;D:D;"True") = 3;"regular";"not regular")
```

[image]

Comment: The number of attendances varies widely between people (I should have made that clear sorry) so I don't think that would work.

Comment: @MichalisM would you have a "regular" when 3 same attendances and 3 same person are under 84 days ? I edited my answer for that, let me know

Comment: Could you clarify the question?
I think you might be on the right track actually, but I can't get the formulas to work on my data. Why are you using the TODAY() function and shouldn't there be something in the brackets?

Comment: I'm using Today() to have the number of day between current date (today 2018-06-04 ). If this number >= 84, result is "True".
There is nothing in brackets.
Do you have an error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Might work (I hate counting days and too little sample data for proper testing):

Select the `Person ID` column (assumed to be B) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,C:C,"<"&(C1+84))>2,COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)=1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of choice <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.